# Modify a canvas using fabric.js without removing existing content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

In my web page there is a canvas with some content and this content is rendered separately (without using fabric.js).

What I want to do is add some content on top of the existing content, using fabric.js . 
I tried to do that as follow (sample code),

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 200 100 L 170 200 z');
path.set({ left: 120, top: 120 });
canvas.add(path);
```

But it will remove the existing content from the canvas.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Where is the canvas with the content already on it? The code you posted works. My best guess would be that you could export your original canvas using canvas.toDataURL() to get a PNG that could be used as the background for your new canvas. Otherwise, you'll have to roll your own method for converting the original canvas to JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the canvas.toDataURL() function as suggested by Jason Maggard:

```
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

var bg = c.toDataURL("image/png");

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setBackgroundImage(bg,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 200 100 L 170 200 z');
path.set({ left: 120, top: 120 });
canvas.add(path);
```

The red background should still be there even after you add the fabricjs code. You could also use the canvas.toDataURL() function as the src of a dynamic image, if you want to be able to move it around/etc.

```
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

var img = new Image();
img.src = c.toDataURL("image/png");

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var oldCanvas = new fabric.Image(img,{ width: c.width, height: c.height });

var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 200 100 L 170 200 z');
path.set({ left: 120, top: 120 });

canvas.add(oldCanvas);
canvas.add(path);
```

Comment: Thanks @Phoenix.
Yes I could use canvas.toDataURL() for this. :)

Comment: @Phoenix What about the performance impact caused due to extraction of base64 data and drawing that data again on canvas ? I have close to 30 canvases rendered and i need to initialize fabric on each of them. It takes it's own sweet time to do that and locks up the fps for me at the moment. Any tips ?

Comment: @Vinay I haven't tried anything like this on so many canvases. I have, however, tried a very large number of images on a single canvas, and the lag was not pretty. There was an article I read a long while ago where a game developer reduced fps issues for mobile by copying to a canvas half the intended size then scaling up. Depending on what you need (and how crisp the frames need to be), you could try something like this to reduce the sheer amount of data that you need to process. There might also be some browser settings related to canvas that you could check out.