# Get FabricJS canvas object from existing HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a HTML5 canvas with a red rectangle:

```
<canvas id="c" width="209" height="209" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute; width: 209px; height: 209px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;" class="lower-canvas"></canvas>
```

Now I would like to use the fabricjs library to draw further lines on it and work against this existing canvas.

But if I do `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');`, the canvas goes blank and all objects on it disappear.

So I am looking for a method to retrieve a fabricjs object from this existing canvas.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I think it's solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063173/modify-a-canvas-using-fabric-js-without-removing-existing-content maybe a dup ?

Comment: are u looking to serialize the canvas? Then you can use JSON.stringify(canvas) to save the canvas json and use canvas.loadFromJSON() to reload it.

Comment: @bfmags - that might work for me, even though I look at it as workaround. I don't understand why an existing canvas html5 element could not be loaded directly by fabricjs without going through making it an image or going through serialization. I was looking for a more straight forward solution, no workarounds. But maybe it's just not possible without working around it, so you might as well go ahead and make your proposals an answer :) thanks to you both for input.

Comment: @Genocide_Hoax - same as comment above, serializing it first seems like a step too much and like hacking around the the problem. but maybe my only option, thanks for your input!

Comment: html5 canvas native API is a bitmap drawing api, is simply a 2D bitmap, while fabricjs adds support for objects